# How to Login To A Website Using Csharp.HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, automation

so i was trying to under what are requests like post and get and other network concepts like headers and cookies. so i thought why not try to logging into a website using POST and cSharp so i tried to Login to A website in this case "accounts.epicgames.com/login"

i tried the following code but it didn't redirect me to the correct page

```
handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = Cookies };
        client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseUrl };

        var formParams = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "epic_username", "x" },
            { "password" ,   "y" }
        };



        var formFormat = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dic);
        var response = await client.PostAsync("login/doLogin", formFormat);

        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

While im sure im missing alot , indeed the response indicated that im still in the same page. 
now i have a couple of question. 
1-do i need to send all form parameters for the post request to be accepted ?
2- if i need to send all params , if a parameter requires clientId how can i send that?

so what is the correct way of making this work. this is my first attempt at networking and i cant find a good place to learn it if theres a good course or book covering this please mention it in the comments.

Comment: Get Telerik Fiddler and start playing with that.  It will tell you what sort of things are required for logging into a given website.  Just turn it on, do a normal login, and it will record the interactions over the wire in detail for you to inspect.

Comment: You need all the `input` elements of the Form (hidden and not), add a value to the elements that require a User value (text and password types, mainly, but you might have checkboxes and captcha) and send them back as a `List<KeyValuePair>`, using a `FormUrlEncodedContent` class (this one you have already).

Comment: The answers to this question depend completely on the web site and how it is programmed. Sometimes they design the login page specifically to make it difficult to do what you are attempting.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ,  thanks for the suggestion ! ,

Comment: @John Wu i was looking for the general way of doing this or good sources that teach different approaches against different website architects , and such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using fiddler for a bit comparing between headers and cookies between my manual website login and login from csharp , i found that i need to firstly send a get request get the cookies the website provide. then add the xsrf token from the cookies to client headers i use to send the post request, heres what i added to my code to get it working

```
var getString = await client.GetStringAsync("doLogin");

    foreach (var xar in Cookies.GetCookies(baseUrl).Cast<Cookie>())
    {
        if (xar.Name == "XSRF-TOKEN")Token = xar.Value;
    }

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-XSRF-TOKEN", Token);
```

Comment: forgot to mention i needed a couple more inputs beside the email and username, but that wasn't the main issue